# It is possible to transfer data to browser from application

Tags: ios

I want to get back some response to browser from application.

Like if I come into application from browser to application using deeplinking then I handle some changes into application and I want to retrive those changes into browser from application.

So help me how it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. What you can do if you need to interact with a web site is to present the user a web view inside your app. That's actually a good practice since you don't send the user outside of your app.

The web view has some delegate methods were you can catch requests and linking.

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with [URL schemes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app) by adding them in your website and make your app handle them. You can pass information in the URL and retrieve it in your app by parsing the URL.